# Are there certain EM frequencies that are impossible to emit?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, atomic-physics, astrophysics, absorption

Every element has absorption lines. Is there some line which is not covered by anything else? Some strange gap in the universe?

Comment: The question in your title is quite a bit more general than the question in the body.

Comment: This strikes me as an ill-defined question - the EM spectrum of frequencies is continuous and unbounded above, while the set of spectral lines is discrete and bounded by the frequency corresponding to the highest binding energy of an innermost electron- How are you comparing these two things? Why would you expect the spectral line to "cover" a significant portion? How broad are the spectral lines here? E.g. does the [Lyman series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyman_series) "cover" the range between 121 nm and 90 nm?

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by ACuriousMind, the uncertainty principle tells us that the frequency of the wave packet associated with a photon, cannot be precisely determined.  With many elements, there is likely to some overlap in their line spectra.  There is, of course, the continuous spectrum produced by an incandescent material.  At other frequencies I'm not too sure. Our high energy machines can produce a wide range of frequencies for gamma rays and x rays. Some cosmic rays can go much higher.  There may be some gaps in what we can do in the ultraviolet, and microwaves (which we started producing in the 30's ) may or may not span the gap between UHF and infrared.